# Insert video in latex

Tags: movie15

Please give latex code to insert a video in latex and hence video should be played in pdf. I wrote this

```
\documentclass[12pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,letterpaper}
\usepackage{movie15}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
 Whispering-gallery mode in a quarter circle:
\begin{figure}[ht]
 \includemovie[
  poster,
  text={\small(srs.mp4)}
 ]{6cm}{6cm}{srs.mp4}
\end{figure}
```

It is compiling but when I open pdf it comes that "Pdf contains media which requires an additional player". What should I do to get it correct this error. Please tell

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Which PDF viewer did you try? You may need to use Adobe Reader.

Comment: I used adobe reader

Comment: Give me any alternative method to run a simple video in latex. That would also be fine. Thanks

Comment: There is a package called `media9` which is newer than `movie15`. But I know very little of these things, so I cannot help any more I'm afraid.

Comment: You can also try to convert your `mp4` file into `swf`

Comment: @ShivamJain Suggestion: Use `swf` files and use a recent version of Adobe Reader.

Comment: That works. But it plays automatically.Is there some control to play it when we click on it?

Comment: Flash support has discontinued from Dec 2020.
Media9 no longer works as above. Fixes are in [Media9 Alternatives](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516029/129388)