# Embedded videos in Latex beamer presentation

Tags: pdftex, video

Other people have asked this question but the posts are either 10+ years old (i.e., completely obsolete) or no relevant/useable answer.

I need to embed a small video (no sound) in a Latex beamer presentation. I write my presentations on Overleaf since it is convenient for packages, but ...

I feel furstrated because the Overleaf documentation, (as usual), is either obsolete or incomplete: i.e.: useless. For embedding videos they provide this:

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/using-media9-to-include-video-and-audio-files/yvdwwvpknjkk

which might have worked 10 years ago but since Flash player is unfortunately not supported anymore ...

I tried to play it with Adobe Acrobat DC: only the .mp3 plays (which I don't care since I m only interested in video, not audio).

Can anyone provide a working example with a modern solution, of how to embed a video in Latex Beamer presentation, and explain by what means (which PDF reader/player) we can use to view the presentation?

----------------EDIT after anonymous comment

I just tried something as simple as:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {\usetheme{Madrid}}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multimedia}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \centering
        \frametitle{Title}
        \movie[width=9cm,height=7cm, poster]{}{New_video.mp4}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

It compiles but simply does not play in Adobe DC or a web browser. (a white rectangle with a hand symbol but nothings plays, and note that the file New_video.mp4 is in the same folder as the generated PDF).

Comment: Did you have a look at section **14 Animations, Sounds, and Slide Transitions** of the beamer manual? It starts with a discussion on how to embed a video.

Comment: Thanks, started to look at it but it seems to be more or less the same

Comment: Look at my post update please. Would be really great to find a way to make that work... i m sure many people are struggling with that... its kinda a nightmare

Comment: Well, I agree that this is an important question, and that other users struggle with this. However, it isn't all that easy to answer your question. Why? First of all, others may not have your video. You can fix this by providing a link to a movie that others can use. So far, so good. But then there is no information on how you compile this file, and which viewer you use. OK, you could add that you use, say, pdflatex and Acrobat reader in full screen mode. Even then one would probably need to specify your OS, and make sure that you have apps installed that allow you to play the media...

Comment: An extensive discussion of this problem is found on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516029/media9-is-becoming-obsolete-dec-2020-any-alternatives-for-embedding-video-audio