# Insert a Desmos graph (not static!) in beamer presentation with Overleaf

Tags: beamer, overleaf, video

I would like to put a Desmos graph in a frame of my beamer presentaton. I do not want to put a pdf or a static image : I would like to be able to play around with the parameters, click on the graph, etc. as I do when I am on the Desmos page (please look at this example : https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nyvi9cvq8f).

I could just put a link to the Desmos page, but I really want to embed it in my presentation so I don't need to move around many tabs because I need many graphs.

I also thought about putting a video (and simply record my screen), but it seems very complicated. I first looked at this post : [Embedded videos in Latex beamer presentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/569206/embedded-videos-in-latex-beamer-presentation). It led me to this post : [Media9 is becoming obsolete Dec 2020. Any alternatives for embedding video/audio in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516029/media9-is-becoming-obsolete-dec-2020-any-alternatives-for-embedding-video-audio).
But unfortunately, I do not understand how to make the first two options work and as for the third option, I can't find Acrobat.exe on my computer (?). It seems like the video option is something complicated with beamers since the flash player is not supported anymore.

Can someone help me or does someone have an idea to help me? I am using Overleaf.

Thank you very much for your attention and your time.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you show a short compilable TeX code showing what you tried?

Comment: Thank you very much! 

Essentially, I tried these two for the video thing

(1) with : \usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multimedia}

\movie[width=9cm,height=7cm, poster]{}{New_video.mp4}

(2) with : \usepackage{media9}

\begin{center}
    \includemedia[width=7.5cm,height=7.5cm,addresource=test.mp4,transparent,activate=pagevisible,flashvars={source=test.mp4 &autoplay=true
    &loop=false}]{}{VPlayer9.swf}   
    \end{center}

As for the option with no video, I haven't find anything useful 

Thank you very much

Comment: FWIW, an interactive item is much more complicated than a video, which is much more complicated than an image.  I'd go for an image with several useful values of `a`, and have that image be a link to the Desmos page.

Comment: That's what I initially wanted to do, but I wanted something more pretty... Thank you for your advice :-)

Comment: There are multiple aspects of this question that are not particular to Overleaf, but I'll just answer the Overleaf-specific part of the question in a comment (I'm on support staff at Overleaf): The Overleaf PDF previewer doesn't support dynamic content. So if you manage to embed something that works, you would need to download the PDF from Overleaf and view it in a suitable viewer that supports the dynamic content.

Comment: That's good to know, I'm just starting to learn LaTeX. Thank you

Comment: mostly your question is not latex related in that the features you are asking about are not available in PDF: the link you give is to a web page not a pdf. Some PDF readers (notably acrobat) have some interactivity and if you restrict to those readers you can use latex to generate PDF, but the PDF will not be usable with most PDF readers. And even with acrobat PDF isn't really designed for the kind of interaction you get on a web page.