# Change in Video embedding?

Tags: beamer, graphics, pdftex, packages, texstudio

I am trying to embed a video in a beamer presentation.
I must specify that the exemple below using `media9` package **was previously working**.
It is not working anymore, and I don't understand why.
I am aware that many similar subjects were created, and from them, I managed to produce the working code linked below.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{title}

    \includemedia[
    width=1\linewidth,height=0.3\linewidth,
    activate=pageopen,
    passcontext,
    addresource=NRCollisionalQuenchToh.mp4,
    flashvars={source=NRCollisionalQuenchToh.mp4
        %&autoplay=true
        %&loop=true
    }  %adjust
    ]{\fbox{Please work?}}{VPlayer.swf}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Once again, this was working, but it's not the case anymore.

I am working on windows 10 using TexStudio as editor.
The miktek console is up-to-date, and I have the latest version of adobe acrobat reader DC (20.013.20064).

It is **compiled without error**, and adobe open the pdf.
Although, once on the slide, a small box appear to say its loading the video.
Once the box show "ready" nothing happen, and **the video don't play**.

Also, I am aware that it should be possible to embed video in beamer directly with the `multimedia` package.
I am totally fine with it, but I just never could get it to work.
I am also aware tht it is possible to have external links, and I know how to do it, but this is not what I am looking for.
Here is my code for that:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\usepackage{multimedia}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{title}
    \movie[
    poster,
    showcontrols=true]
    {Embedded}{water.avi}\\
    \movie[externalviewer]{External link}{water.avi}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I am open to any solutions for embedded videos in a latex beamer, whatever video format I should use.
I would prefer solutions using the `media9` package, to be able to send the pdf to someone, whithout having to dend the video on the side, but at this point, I am fine with anything.

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: Can people watching this tell me if this bit of code is working for them at least? So I can have an idea about where the problem is coming from...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adobe will end its support for Flash by the end of December. Did you perhaps consent to stop using Flash in Acrobat Reader?

[image]

Although this can be undone in the settings, it might be possible that AR updates after the 31st December will ultimately disable Flash usage.

Video playback without Flash is possible in Acrobat Reader, but currently no control buttons are provided for user interaction.

Another [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/516102) proposes a command for embedding MP4 video without Flash, but it is subject to the limitation given in the previous sentence.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I was thinking about this as well.
I did not accept it on my browser, but this message is not showing on Adobe, so I may have accepted it there. How can I change it back? My presentation is due early december, so flash should still work I guess.

But many thanks for your answer again.

Comment: It is at the top of the "Edit"-->"Preferences (Settings?)"-->"3D & Multimedia" tab in Acrobat Reader. (I don't have the English version of AR here, so it is my translation.) Hope it works for you.

Comment: You're right for the path:  "Edit"-->"Preferences" --> "3D & Multimedia".
Then I ticked the box "Use Flash Player for playing 3D and multimedia content".
However, after recompiling, and reopenning the pdf, the video still don't play.
I think I'll just go with the external link.
The answer you linked seems to use modification of the "RichMedia" part of AR, which is not free. So I am not sure I can use it, but thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Did you test whether both RichMedia methods (`media9` and [`\embedvideo`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/516102)) work with the example video file `example-movie.mp4` from pkg `mwe`? Maybe your video file has an encoding issue.