# Alternatives for media9 after Dec 2020 in overleaf

Tags: overleaf, media9

I would like to know if there are alternatives for media9 package in overleaf for embedding video / animation. This page says the package is obsolete: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/obsolete-using-media9-to-include-video-and-audio-files/yvdwwvpknjkk

I saw a similar question [Media9 is becoming obsolete Dec 2020. Any alternatives for embedding video/audio in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516029/media9-is-becoming-obsolete-dec-2020-any-alternatives-for-embedding-video-audio/) in TeX community, however, that seems to be specific to TeX and not overleaf (I tried the sample at the end of answer in that post and it did not work in overleaf i.e., after I made sure I have the graphic package is included and using embedvideo tag)

Comment: (I'm on the support team at Overleaf.) The example from that post works for me in Overleaf without any changes, and the embedded video plays for me in Adobe Reader after trusting the document. You won't be able to play the video directly in Overleaf's viewer, but it should work in an external viewer provided you enabled the dynamic content in your PDF viewer settings.

Comment: @PaulGessler The pdf from overleaf doesn't work for me (on windows 10 with a current adobe reader).  There can be installations where the needed flash player is still active, but in general one should assume that the support is gone. AlexG's example in the linked questions works a bit for me, but there are no controls and it is not possible to restart the movie, imho an external link is really better currently. (And it is not a latex problem, including a video with adobe pro doesn't give a better experience).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer in my comment above, “that post” refers to AlexG’s answer in the linked question. Sorry for not being fully clear. I know that we should assume Flash support is gone. This is why we have marked the media9 example as obsolete until an official alternative emerges.

Comment: For reference, here is an Overleaf project that uses [AlexG's Flash-free code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/516102/21344) : https://www.overleaf.com/read/rcfqksxktygc . If you download the PDF, the video should be playable in an external PDF viewer, provided the viewer supports it and you've allowed the content.

Comment: The pdf from the https://www.overleaf.com/read/rcfqksxktygc does not play the  video

Comment: Just to let everyone know: The old, allegedly obsolete movie15 package seems to work still fine for playing movies, at least when using Adobe Reader.  (I checked it only for a few mp4 movies and only on macos...)