# Is there a way to use the alternative code for a thesis/dissertation in a certain thesis template?

Tags: pdf, include, appendix, video

Now that Adobe Flash is dead, I was hoping if anyone else discover a new way to embed a video in a .pdf file instead of a hyperlink to another file in LaTeX and I have come across this link:

[Media9 is becoming obsolete Dec 2020. Any alternatives for embedding video/audio in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516029/media9-is-becoming-obsolete-dec-2020-any-alternatives-for-embedding-video-audio/516102#516102)

and used the code in this link. It works; however, the code only seems to work by itself as an individual document. I was hoping if there is a way to use the code so that it works for a thesis/dissertation separated by front and main matter.

My videos are supposed to appear in the appendix which is a separate file titled 'AppendixH.tex' and include the appendix in the main matter. All my appendices begins with

```
\chapter{AppendixH title}
\label{AppendixH}

...
```

I was hoping to embed for one of my videos using the same template, but it doesn't work.

```
\chapter{Animations of Wave Propagation}

\label{AppendixH}

\embedvideo{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{gaussian_smoothramp.png}}{gaussian_smoothramp.mp4}
```

and the main.tex has the code

```
\include{Appendices/AppendixH}
```

with the video-embedding code in the preamble of main.tex.

Comment: You might be able ti include the graphic with `graphicx`, or at least embed it into a standalone PDF and include that with `graphicx`.

Comment: I don't see anything in AlexG's code which is problematic with \include. But perhaps your template contains something else that disturbs the video.