# Including a movie in a beamer presentation using Media9

Tags: beamer, movie15

I'm trying to include a movie in my presentation using media9, but I got the error that flash is not supported any more so what is a good easy alternative

```
 \RequirePackage{media9}
 \documentclass[10pt,aspectratio=169,xcolor=table]{beamer}
\end{document}
\begin{frame}{Movie}
\includemedia[activate=pageopen,width=200pt,height=150pt]{}{Midterm.mov} 
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Media9 is becoming obsolete Dec 2020. Any alternatives for embedding video/audio in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516029/134144) might be interesting.

Comment: This is discussed in another question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516029/media9-is-becoming-obsolete-dec-2020-any-alternatives-for-embedding-video-audio