# specifying position of movies in beamer

Tags: beamer, video

I have a frame in beamer which includes three figure. I want to open three different videos when I click on each of these figures.

I know how to make a frame with a figure so that when I click on the figure a video opens. I do it by using

```
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{dynamics}
  \centering
    \movie[externalviewer]{\includegraphics[width=\textheight, keepaspectratio]{defects.png}}{video1.mp4}
\end{frame}
```

However, I do not know how to do this with three figures and videos. Could someone please help me?

To make a frame with three different figures (without movies) I used the following

```
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Results}
        \begin{textblock*}{6cm}(7cm,6.25cm) % {block width} (coords)
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{bac.jpg}
\end{textblock*}
    \begin{textblock*}{6cm}(0.5cm,2.5cm) % {block width} (coords)
\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{cells.png}
\end{textblock*}
    \begin{textblock*}{6cm}(9.0cm,2.5cm) % {block width} (coords)
\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{cellsc.pdf}
\end{textblock*}
        \begin{textblock*}{6cm}(2cm,6cm) % {block width} (coords)
\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{micro.png}
\end{textblock*} 
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Please be aware that since **February 2021** there was a negative change regarding the support of embedded movies in PDF: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516029/ and https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/How_can_I_embed_a_video_in_my_PDF_using_LaTeX%3F.