# Embed .mp4 file in LaTeX document

Tags: media9

Is this possible anymore since Adobe discontinued FlashPlayer?

```
Since Adobe no longer supports Flash Player after December 31, 2020
and blocked Flash content from running in Flash Player beginning January 12, 2021,
Adobe strongly recommends all users immediately uninstall Flash Player to help protect their systems.
```

I'm using `media9` package and Adobe Acrobat is asking me to install flashplayer.
Any alternative as June 2021?

Comment: Please try the following temporary solutions: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/516102 , https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/592827 .

Comment: Thanks, @AlexG! After looking at that page and see how many modifications I have to make, I think I'll skip for now.