# Media9 video appears black

Tags: beamer, media9

I have embedded a video (.mp4, ~1mb) in my presentation using `media9` as followed:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \includemedia[
      width=0.4\linewidth,
      height=0.45\linewidth,
      activate=pageopen,        
      addresource=Video.mp4,
      flashvars={
          source=Video.mp4}
    ]{}{VPlayer.swf}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The positioning and the rest seem to be fine on `Overleaf`, but whenever I try playing it back on my PC using `Adobe Acrobat Reader DC` I only get a black video. Weird enough, I had no issues opening videos before and I have not updated any of the pdf tools on my pc or another device where the behaviour is indeed the same.

1. Any idea of what might be causing this error?
2. Is there another way of playing back videos embedded in pdfs?

[image]

Comment: Works for me with `example-movie.mp4` (from pkg `mwe`). But note that on Windows, the video can be played only once by click, unless you tweak the Windows registry somewhat. See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/516102

Comment: Thank you for looking into it @AlexG . Unfortunately, I cannot display that video either. Could it be the compiler that I am using? (pdfLatex) Or adobe acrobat (latest release, 32-bit for some reason...)

Comment: It should work with any compiler. I tested with `pdflatex` and AR-DC-2021.005.20060.

Comment: I guess you know already that much of the media playback functionality in PDF and Acrobat Reader is gone since FlashPlayer was retired by Adobe.

Comment: @AlexG That is likely making things worse. I downloaded Adobe Reader XI and it does now work. It seems the main issue was the reader. Any other pdf reader that you might recommend?

Comment: Not really. All user interaction with video was programmed into `VPlayer.swf` using Flash elements and ActionScript (the scripting language of FlashPlayer) and thus depends on FlashPlayer, which is no more. And for the same reason, other PDF viewers cannot really do a better job here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem, in this case, is not Latex, but the pdf reader that has been used to visualize the presentation. As pointed out in the comments, Flash player is no longer supported (ended 2020) and thus many new pdf readers do not work with the playback of embedded `swf` files.

The solution in my case was installing Adobe Reader XI.