# AlexG's code for video presentation

Tags: beamer, adobe, video

I am using the code presented by AlexG to present videos in slides prepared with beamer.

The code can be found here: [Media9 is becoming obsolete Dec 2020. Any alternatives for embedding video/audio in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516029/media9-is-becoming-obsolete-dec-2020-any-alternatives-for-embedding-video-audio) and uses pdfbase package,

I wanna if is it possible to loop the video, i.e., repeat it automatically over and over ...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to achieve looping with Alexander Grahn's code, since it uses Flashless Rich Media, which doesn't have a way to achieve this. It is in fact "Plain Rich Media".

There is a way to do this with the older mechanism "Multimedia" (also called "Renditions") which is also implemented in some TeX packages (notably movie15, ConTeXt and pdfextra) and also this is what [Fritz used in his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/592827/125126). With the "Multimedia" mechanism there is an option called `RC` that controls "Repeat count". The setting that might interest you is `0`, which means loop forever.

In ConTeXt, this option isn't exposed.

With movie15 you can achieve this by using `repeat` option (with value of 0 or no value at all).

Fritz's code could be modified to add this option. Let me know if you are interested.

With `pdfextra` you can use the `repeat` key with value `0`, and you probably also want autoplay and a preview image:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfextra}

\begin{document}

\render[video.mp4][
  repeat=0,
  aactions=\renditionautoplay,
]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image.pdf}}

\end{document}
```

More specific things could be achievable with JavaScript, but that is Acrobat Reader only.

And what you may find is, that in fact the `RC` option I describe above, doesn't work in Acrobat Reader(*), there is no repeat! It works in Foxit Reader thoug, and I would generally reccomend it for PDF + multimedia on Windows. Okular also works on Linux and I guess adding support to Evince wouldn't be too hard.

(*) Also I couldn't get any recent Acrobat installation to play multimedia at all, I am still unsure about the cause.

Comment: Thanks a lot for investigating this!

Comment: Thanks a lot Michal! It is really a great help!