# Embedding a video loop in beamer

Tags: beamer, media9, video

I'm trying to embed a short video (less than two seconds) in a beamer presentation and I need it to start automatically and keep repeating while the slide is shown.

After trying many solutions that didn't work due to Flash not having support anymore, I managed to embed the video using the code by @AlexG in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/516102/263164

Regardless, this solution doesn't include an option for looping.
I've tried to add it in the *FlashVars* as it is done in *media9* but it doesn't work for me.

I'm pasting below a compilable example of my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[bigfiles]{pdfbase}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\embedvideo{smm}{
  \group_begin:
  \leavevmode
  \tl_if_exist:cTF{file_\file_mdfive_hash:n{#3}}{
    \tl_set_eq:Nc\video{file_\file_mdfive_hash:n{#3}}
  }{
    \IfFileExists{#3}{}{\GenericError{}{File~`#3'~not~found}{}{}}
    \pbs_pdfobj:nnn{}{fstream}{{}{#3}}
    \pbs_pdfobj:nnn{}{dict}{
      /Type/Filespec/F~(#3)/UF~(#3)
      /EF~<</F~\pbs_pdflastobj:>>
    }
    \tl_set:Nx\video{\pbs_pdflastobj:}
    \tl_gset_eq:cN{file_\file_mdfive_hash:n{#3}}\video
  }
  %
  \pbs_pdfobj:nnn{}{dict}{
    /Type/RichMediaInstance/Subtype/Video
    /Asset~\video
    /Params~<</FlashVars (
      source=#3&
      skin=SkinOverAllNoFullNoCaption.swf&
      skinAutoHide=true&
      skinBackgroundColor=0x5F5F5F&
      skinBackgroundAlpha=0.75
    )>>
  }
  %
  \pbs_pdfobj:nnn{}{dict}{
    /Type/RichMediaConfiguration/Subtype/Video
    /Instances~[\pbs_pdflastobj:]
  }
  %
  \pbs_pdfobj:nnn{}{dict}{
    /Type/RichMediaContent
    /Assets~<<
      /Names~[(#3)~\video]
    >>
    /Configurations~[\pbs_pdflastobj:]
  }
  \tl_set:Nx\rmcontent{\pbs_pdflastobj:}
  %
  \pbs_pdfobj:nnn{}{dict}{
    /Activation~<<
      /Condition/\IfBooleanTF{#1}{PV}{XA}
      /Presentation~<</Style/Embedded>>
    >>
    /Deactivation~<</Condition/PI>>
  }
  %
  \hbox_set:Nn\l_tmpa_box{#2}
  \tl_set:Nx\l_box_wd_tl{\dim_use:N\box_wd:N\l_tmpa_box}
  \tl_set:Nx\l_box_ht_tl{\dim_use:N\box_ht:N\l_tmpa_box}
  \tl_set:Nx\l_box_dp_tl{\dim_use:N\box_dp:N\l_tmpa_box}
  \pbs_pdfxform:nnnnn{1}{1}{}{}{\l_tmpa_box}
  %
  \pbs_pdfannot:nnnn{\l_box_wd_tl}{\l_box_ht_tl}{\l_box_dp_tl}{
    /Subtype/RichMedia
    /BS~<</W~0/S/S>>
    /Contents~(embedded~video~file:#3)
    /NM~(rma:#3)
    /AP~<</N~\pbs_pdflastxform:>>
    /RichMediaSettings~\pbs_pdflastobj:
    /RichMediaContent~\rmcontent
  }
  \phantom{#2}
  \group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Title}
    Some text.
    \centering
    \embedvideo*{\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{res/thumbnail.png}}{res/video.mp4}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

When opening the resulting PDF with Foxit the video plays once and then stops. Furthermore, if I change to another slide and then come back to this one, the box where the video should be gets totally black.

¿Does someone know any way to fix this, either with this method or with another one?

I've considered creating an animation from the frames of the video, but I would prefer to avoid such solution if possible.

Thanks for your help,

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: If the sequence is that short, and if no audio is involved, you might as well try to embed and animate the single frames of the sequence using the `animate` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was also interested in having embedded videos looping this way. You mentioned Flash variables and the `media9` package in your question, so I tried the following:

```
  \pbs_pdfobj:nnn{}{dict}{
    /Type/RichMediaInstance/Subtype/Video
    /Asset~\video
    /Params~<</FlashVars (
      source=#3&
      skin=SkinOverAllNoFullNoCaption.swf&
      skinAutoHide=true&
      skinBackgroundColor=0x5F5F5F&
      skinBackgroundAlpha=0.75&
      loop=true
    )>>
  }
```

Opening the compiled PDF in Okular, embedded videos are now playing on an infinite loop.