# How can I embed or link to a video in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, adobe, video

I have made a video which I want to embed into my beamer presentation. However, I couldn't find a way to do it. I did some research and found out that since Adobe had discontinued Flash LaTeX couldn't embed video's onto pdf's anymore. So are there still ways to have a link to my own video or let it play in a frame evironment

Comment: Have you checked this? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516029/media9-is-becoming-obsolete-dec-2020-any-alternatives-for-embedding-video-audio/

Comment: @Tom I did! I saw that the question you are referring to is from two years ago, when adobe flash was just discontinued. So I was wondering if there are another alternatives which can be implemented in 2022.