# Embed audio in LaTeX

Tags: audio

I've been looking through the documentation and on this website for ways to embed audio in LaTeX, but it seems the media9 library is already discontinued. So my question is is there a way other than media9 to insert audio into PDFs in LaTeX.

In short, there is a way to place as a player (have control with play or pause buttons) embedded audio in the PDF

Comment: Welcome to TeXsx! The media9 package is not discontinued (last update Aug 2022). See the [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/media9) for numerous examples

Comment: there is a long discussion about the "after flash" options in https://gitlab.com/agrahn/media9/-/issues/9. You can also check https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516029/2388