# Can we play the video in the pdf without having to change the setting in Adobe Reader using media9 package?

Tags: pdf, media9, video

Good evening/morning!

Straight to the point, I am trying to embed videos in pdfs and that I did manage to do that
thanks to the help provided in the answers to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516029/media9-is-becoming-obsolete-dec-2020-any-alternatives-for-embedding-video-audio).

The first problem I faced on windows was that videos didn't work but only the audio like this:
[image]

So, I found the solution to this problem[image]

My question is can we play the video in the pdf without having to change the setting in Adobe Reader using media9 package.

Comment: Welcome to TeX StackExchange! Based on what you've said, it seems like Adobe Reader does this for security reasons—it isn't related to how you made your LaTeX document. If you could disable a user's security settings simply by compiling your LaTeX document differently, then that sounds a little like a computer virus. (I'm not too familiar with Adobe products, so perhaps only certain types of videos get blocked, and a solution still may exist. I'm a little doubtful though.)