# Embedding .mp4 in Beamer

Tags: beamer, video, gif

I have a file `movie.gif` that I converted into `movie.mp4`.

I'd like to add it to my Beamer presentation.

I tried:

```
\documentclass[10pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}

\includemedia[
  label=vid,
  addresource=movie.mp4,
  activate=pageopen,
  width=5cm, height=4cm,
  flashvars={
     source=movie.mp4
    &loop=true
  }
]{}{VPlayer.swf}

\mediabutton[
  mediacommand=vid:playPause,
]{\fbox{Play/Pause}}
\end{document}
```

Do you know why this would not work`?
Help would be really appreciatedd!

**EDIT:** I tried several approaches:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xmpmulti}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \transduration<0-10>{0}
        \multiinclude[<+->][format=png, graphics={width=\textwidth}]{something
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This produces many slides...

[image]

Another approach:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Embedded Animation}
  \animategraphics[loop,controls,width=\linewidth]{10}{something-}{0}{16}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unless you have an ancient pdf viewer, it might be easier to include a gif: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240247/36296

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516029/36296

Comment: Thank you. I'm not very familiar with the command line. What would be the easiest method do split the gif?

Comment: If the gif does not contain any sensitive information, you could use an online service like https://convertio.co/gif-png/ (no idea how good or bad they are compared to others, was just the first hit in duckduckgo)

Comment: Do you know how I can rename (72 files) in latex? I'd like to use your code.

Comment: Renaming files is a job for your operating system, not for latex.

Comment: To test the different solutions, you could rename a couple of images by hand and check if you like the results. You could also try @AlexG's solution https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240387/36296

Comment: Okay. Can I modify \transduration? My structure is 'something- (1)' ... 'something- (73)'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149745/discussion-between-sylvia-and-samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz).

Comment: You want to avoid spaces in the file names and also remove the `()` around the number. The files should be called `something-1.png` to `something-73.png` and then try `\begin{frame}
        \transduration<0-72>{0}
        \multiinclude[<+->][format=png, graphics={width=\textwidth},start=1]{something}
    \end{frame}` If you have adobe reader, it will need to be used in presentation mode for the automatic changing between slides.

Comment: If you are using Linux then the solution might be to use a PDF viewer which supports nedia/animations as, e.g., okular or pdfpc. The default viewers (e.g., evince) don't work. For testing, you can download the pdf from `https://github.com/pdfpc/pdfpc` (and there: Sample presentations --> Embedded movies). This could also help to find out if (or not) it is your viewer.

Comment: I could rename the images. something-0.png to something-72.png.
I could not manage to properly embed the images (see edit)

Comment: @Sylvia If more than two users commented on your question, you need to start your comments with `@username`. Otherwise they don't get notified about your replies.

Comment: @Sylvia What do you mean with `properly embed the images`?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz see edit. If I use that code, I get a sequence of slides. Each slide shows the GIF and I get a long compilation time.

Comment: The code will create one slide for each png. With a suitable pdf viewer, the `\transduration{0}` will automatically change the slide and thus create an animation. In my opinion, that's the safest approach. Worst case, you can still manually switch the slides. If you only want a single slide, try the code by @AlexG

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz
The code by AlexG is nice, but the play button is missing (See edit)

Comment: @Sylvia Alex's code works fine for me in adobe reader.